# Django Tastypie - Inserting parent and child objects in a single atomic transaction

Tags: django, postgresql, rest, tastypie

I am trying to implement REST API using PostgreSQL, Tastypie and Django. I managed to implement [GET] API endpoint, but I'm having troubles with implementing [POST] API operation. The cause of my troubles is the fact that I have a table "parent" which can have many child objects defined in Django. The definition of models is below:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test_parent'

class Child(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='components')
    is_mandatory = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    is_visible_in_table = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    is_visible_in_form = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    options = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=False)
    note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test_child'
```

This is the definition of Tastypie resources:

```
class ChildResource(ModelResource):
    parent = fields.ToOneField('app.api.resources.test.ParentResource', attribute='parent')

    class Meta:
        list_allowed_methods = ('get', 'post',)
        detail_allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete',)
        authorization = AnonymousCanPostAuthorization()
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(
            ApiKeyAuthentication(),
            CookieBasicAuthentication(),
            Authentication(),
        )
        resource_name = 'test/child'
        queryset = Child.objects.prefetch_related('component').filter(is_active=True)
        always_return_data = True

        filtering = {
            "id": ('exact',),
            "components": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

class ParentResource(ModelResource):
    owner = fields.ToOneField(
        UserResource,
        attribute='owner',
        full=True,
        null=True
    )
    components = fields.ToManyField(
        ChildResource,
        attribute='components',
        full=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'test/parent'
        queryset = Parent.objects.prefetch_related('components').filter(is_active=True)
        always_return_data = True
        list_allowed_methods = ('get', 'post',)
        detail_allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete',)
        authorization = AnonymousCanPostAuthorization()
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(
            ApiKeyAuthentication(),
            CookieBasicAuthentication(),
            Authentication(),
        )

        filtering = {
            "id": ('exact',),
        }
```

As said, [GET] is working fine and I get the parent with nested component within 'components' attribute which is what I want.

With the implementation I'm having several issues:

1. I cannot make an insert without specifying parent attribute (`resource_uri` in fact). But I don't know this at the moment of inserting since it will be assigned upon inserting parent object. If I try to insert without that attribute, or with null value or with empty string I get an error, but If I add any valid resource URI to any other parent object, the insert succeeds and child objects get the correct IDs after insert (not the one I defined in JSON). **What is the correct way of handling this issue of specifying parent resource URI?**
2. In case of an error during executing insert statements, I get partial insert. For instance, in child objects, a parent URI was not provided and I got an exception. But the parent was inserted. This is not how I would like it to be implemented. I would like to have an atomic transaction where everything (parent and child objects) or nothing is inserted. **How to implement atomic transaction with Tastypie and Django?**

Below is the JSON object I'm sending to the API endpoint using [POST] operation.

```
{
    "title": "Parent object",
    "owner": "/api/v1/user/2",
    "is_private": true,
    "components": [{
        "is_mandatory": false,
        "is_visible_in_form": true,
        "is_visible_in_table": false,
        "note": null,
        "parent": "",
        "options": null,
        "title": "Child element 1"
    }, {
        "is_mandatory": false,
        "is_visible_in_form": true,
        "is_visible_in_table": false,
        "note": null,
        "parent": "",
        "options": null,
        "title": "Child element 2"
    }]
}
```

I tried to make different inserts with parent resource URI with values null and empty string. this was unsuccessful, but when I used existing resource URI that was successful and correct. Child resources were related to the newly added parent object?!

Regarding atomic transactions I am not sure how to implement this. I know that Django has some level of support for atomic transactions, but not sure how to integrate this into tastypie code.